# Linear interpolation in PromQL or MetricsQL

Tags: promql, metricsql, victoriametrics

I am evaluating VictoriaMetrics for an IoT application where we sometimes have gaps in a series due to hardware or communication issues. In some time series reporting situations it is helpful for us to interpolate values for the missing time intervals. I see that [MetricsQL](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/wiki/MetricsQL) (which extends PromQL) has a `keep_last_value()` function that will fill gaps by holding the last observed value until a new one appears (which will be helpful to us) but in some situations a linear interpolation between the values before and after the gap is a more realistic estimate for the missing portion. Is there a function in PromQL or MetricsQL that will do linear interpolation of missing data in a series, or is it possible to construct a more complex query that will achieve this?

**Clarifying the desired interpolation**

What I would like is a simple interpolation between the points immediately before and after the gap; this is, I believe, what TimescaleDB's [interpolate()](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#interpolate) function does. In other words, if my time series is:

```
(1:00, 2)
(2:00, 4)
(3:00, NaN)
(4:00, 5)
(5:00, 1)
```

I would like the interpolated 3:00 value to be **4.5**, half way between the points immediately before and after. I don't want it to be 6 (which is what I would get by extrapolating from the points before the missing one, ignoring the points after) and I don't want whatever value I would get if I did linear regression on the whole series and interpolated at 3:00 (presumably 3, or something close to it).

Of course, this is a simple illustration and it's also possible that the gap could last more than one time step. But in that case I would still like the interpolation to be based solely off of the points immediately before and immediately after the gap, ignoring the rest of the series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Final answer**

Use the `interpolate` function, now available in VictoriaMetrics starting from [v1.38.0](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/releases).

**Original suggestion**

*This does not achieve the exact interpolation requested in the revised question, but may be useful for others with slightly different requirements*

Try combining [predict_linear](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#predict_linear) function with `default` operator from [MetricsQL](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/wiki/MetricsQL) in the following way:

```
metric default predict_linear(metric[1h], 0)
```

Try modifying the value in square brackets in order to get the desired level of interpolation.

Comment: Interesting idea, but reading up on `predict_linear` it doesn't appear that it would do the kind of interpolation I'm looking for. I've added a section to the question clarifying exact behavior that I'm seeking (which I believe is the same as TimescaleDB's `interpolate()`, for reference). Would `predict_linear` achieve this? Or is there another way?

Comment: Thanks for the updated question! I just added `interpolate` function into VictoriaMetrics - see [this commit](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/commit/5d3db3ff7cd137ab81bfedcbb0e12ccd1a670479) for details. It will be included in the next release.
In the mean time you can build VictoriaMetrics from sources according to [these docs](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-build-from-sources)

Comment: Excellent. I look forward to trying it out.

Comment: FYI, the `interpolate` function is available in VictoriaMetrics starting from [v1.38.0](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/releases)